# CSS gradient feature seems like using too much cpu power am i doing anything wrong?

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

Alright now i am trying to make a cool looking table with using CSS gradient feature which is supported by firefox,opera,chrome.

It looks great but it lags too much. When i scroll down the page it lags greatly. It is slow even at super fast computer so it is not related computer. I also tried with different browsers still lagging. When i disable gradient background color feature it returns normal.

So how can i fix this issue or are there any other way i can make cool looking table. thank you.

this is how does table look http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/4905/howlook.png

This is an example class i use for table tds

```
 .ML0
    {
                  color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgb(229,229,229);
        background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(229,229,229)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(242,242,242)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(255,255,255)) );
        background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(229,229,229) 9%, rgb(242,242,242) 55%, rgb(255,255,255) 78% );
        background: -o-linear-gradient( bottom, rgb(229,229,229) 9%, rgb(242,242,242) 55%, rgb(255,255,255) 78% );
        background: -ms-linear-gradient( bottom, rgb(229,229,229) 9%, rgb(242,242,242) 55%, rgb(255,255,255) 78% );
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    }
```

Comment: You could use a semi-transparent 1px wide, white gradient image; it's not the best practice, but it would need less rendering time.

Comment: can you explain detailed i didn't get it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Monster. @BoltClock has your answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a problem that browser vendors are the ones supposed to fix, not you. You're using CSS3 gradients normally.

I suggest you file bug reports with the respective vendors instead. If you need good scrolling performance, just put up with an alternative for now. Background images are great for this; you're not required to do *everything* with CSS.

Comment: yes i am also thinking about that. but it didn't come to me logical. why would it lag too much ? i mean what causes too much cpu power usage. When i scroll down i see that it uses 1 cpu 100% and my cpu speed is 4.8 ghz core i7 2600k. it is so weird. actually the main problem is i can't draw images. but i am thinking about designing it as gradient and take screenshot and extract td bgs and use them. i don't know. so there aren't any way that i can make it run faster ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: I really don't think so. Most rendering performance problems are browser bugs and things you can't do much about.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a gallery on my site; in the end, I just gave up and left Chrome (the fastest renderer) with the nice effects (box shadow). Those browser vendors really need to sort their acts out, seeing as CSS3 is becoming pretty mainstream. Let's just ignore IE < 9.

Comment: yes i ignore ie 9. chrome and firefox are the best at the moment.

Comment: can i make it this way. i make a css sprite and use it as background position and repeat ? can css sprite images be used as background image while repeating to fill ? would this way be more performance wise ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: If you make your gradient sprites really tall and stack them vertically, you can.

Comment: seems like i will stick with css sprites and  make them repeat for bg. currently the performance of gradient is incredibly bad.